# How to filter entites scanned by LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate.

I need to filter entities which are managed by `EntityManager` by custom annotation. `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` allows to set a list of packages which are scanned but filters seems to be hardcoded in `DefaultPersistenceUnitManager`.

Otherwise `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` (Hibernate specific) has this feature (method `setEntityTypeFilters`) but can't be used with Spring Data JPA Repositories which require `EntityManagerFactory`.

How can I apply entity filtering to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem: I want to "exclude" some Entities while still using package scanning provided by `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. In my case, I wanted to make use of `@Profile(...)` annotation used by spring since I need certain entities only if a specific profile is active. 
I solved it by implementing a `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` which removes classes that were added by the scanner. It might not be the most elegant solution, but it works (Spring 4.1.2).

```
public class ProfileAwarePersistenceUnitPostProcessor implements PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    /**
     * Post process the persistence unit and remove Entity classes that require a specific spring profile
     * if profile is not active.
     * 
     * @param pui The persistence unit that was put together so far.
     * @see org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitPostProcessor#postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.MutablePersistenceUnitInfo)
     */
    @Override
    public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui) {
        // Check for null to be sure.
        if (pui.getManagedClassNames() != null) {
            Iterator<String> iterator = pui.getManagedClassNames().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String className = iterator.next();
                try {
                    Class<?> entityClass = Class.forName(className);
                    Profile profileAnnotation = entityClass.getAnnotation(Profile.class);
                    if (profileAnnotation != null) {
                        String[] requiredProfiles = profileAnnotation.value();
                        if (!environment.acceptsProfiles(requiredProfiles)) {
                            Logging.debug("Removing class " + className + " from persistence unit since none of the required profiles is active "
                                    + StringUtils.join(", ", requiredProfiles));
                            iterator.remove();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // Something must have gone wrong during scanning if class is suddenly not found anymore.
                    Logging.warn("Class " + className + " not found  while post processing persistence unit.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any other annotation can be used instead of Profile.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot, just use `@EntityScan` as described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration).

If – as expressed in the comments to this question – you need to work with multiple data sources, have a look at the [corresponding project in the  Spring Data example repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources).

Comment: `@EntityScan` does not support custom filtering (only package names). Also I need two separate entity manager factories for two databases. That's why I want explicitly configure `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Comment: Then I suggest you are more precise on what you mean by "filter" in you your original post. Also, if you need to work with two datasource, mentioning that in the question would've been helpful, too. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and sorry I was not precise. The feature I need is exactly what `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` is doing in `setEntityTypeFilters`.  Now I use solution similiar to example project you mentioned - entities grouped in packages per database. But with growing number of entities I would like to organize them like in project Sagan - package per feature. In my case one package would contain entites from two databases, so I wanted distinguish them by custom annotation (which would be filtered by `TypeFilter`).