# Spring Boot: only discover JPA entity in test profile

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to have an `@Entity` that is only used for testing. This is because I want to test a `@MappedSupertype` without creating a dependency to a real entity that extends it.

The source file is in `src/test/java` but when running the application in Eclipse, the entity is discovered (and for example creates a table on schema export). Is there something like `@Profile("test")` where I can configure the entity outside of the application (i.e. in the test source)?

Answer (score 0):

Place your entity `src/test/java` and it is naturally not registered into Hibernate in production, because test folder is not visible to production classes

Comment: I'm already doing that. But entities are not components and treated differently (e.g. `@Profile` doesn't work).

Comment: yeah, sorry I got confused before. I updated my answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, sources are already separated. But in development, test code is executed regardless. This isn't a serious problem, just a bit inconvenient. Seems like their is no easy solution though... I would have to implement it myself like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010764/5519485 but that may be overkill for now...